# Developing for IOS on 10.6.4

Tags: ios, macos

Ill start developing for IOS but the hardware I got only suport up to 10.6.4
I know that Xcode 4.2 seems to work on Snowleopard...
but the last version requires 10.7.4, in there anyway to make the last version work on the 10.6? If not, if I just use the 4.2, can I still develop with no problems? what Im going to be missing out?
Thanks

Edit: Thanks guys, Ill be building myself a hackintosh...

Comment: To clarify: you want to develop for iOS (iPhone, iPad) but your current MAC computer only allow you to install 10.6.4?

Comment: What is your hardware?

Comment: @MarcusAdams old macbook pro c3d 2gb of ram

Comment: @user1417670 THen, you can use an old version of Xcode at the link provided in my answer. But unfortunately, you may need to consider buying a new MAC computer because of the AppStore requirements (Apple is raising the minimum requirements regularly). Also, you can't develop for the latest iOS devices with an old version of Xcode.

Comment: @user1417670, please don't add "solved" to you question's title. instead mark the most helpful answer

Comment: Lion only requires 2GB of RAM. Have you tried installing Lion? You won't be able to install Mountain Lion. Another cheap route is a used newer model Mac Mini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Older versions of Xcode are still available:**

If you can't install the latest version of Xcode on your MAC, you can get older versions at [connect.apple.com](http://connect.apple.com).

**Notes:**

- However, they won't come with the latest SDKs.
- And you can't develop for the latest iOS devices with an old version
  of Xcode.

In short, you will probably need to upgrade your hardware in order to develop using the laters version of Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Apple are very sneaky - they want to sell hardware - so by dropping support for various OS versions in Xcode and not supporting older hardware with newer OSes they are effectively forcing developers to buy the latest hardware to keep up to date with software development.

You can still develop older iOS apps (i.e. using older SDKs and targeting older iOS versions) using an older version of Xcode (Apple do at least make the older versions of Xcode available through the developer portal). However, you'll need to carefully figure out what iOS versions you can target because Apple are also increasing the minimum app specifications in order to submit new apps and updates to the App-Store. So soon enough it won't be possible to submit apps developed using Xcode 4.2 to the store and you will need to update the Apple hardware you develop on if you want to make apps that will be submitted to the store.

The most annoying thing about this is that you can't even use an older Apple computer as a build server. I have a Mac mini which is less than 5 years old and I can't use it for development any more - it would be perfect as a build server!

Comment: [Starting May 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built for iOS devices with Retina display and iPhone apps must also support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=3212013b). This actually means that you need a quite modern Xcode, as configuring a project, developing and testing might be very hard in older Xcode versions — if not impossible.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Yes - that was my point. Thanks for adding the extra supporting information :)